# DataBinding textboxes with an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, data-binding

I've been doing some research, and essentially have come up empty. I would think this is probably easy to figure out, but well beyond my current knowledge. This is regarding the two text boxes.

I would like to have it so I can search for a word in the searchText box and the translated text would appear in the the searchResults text box. (The xml file is located at https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgw84kqj2k1bwq1/JapaneseEnglishData.xml?dl=0. However, at the bottom of the post is a sample of it). Does anyone have any insight on how I could accomplish this?

```
<Window x:Class="BeginnersJapanese.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData"
                   Source="https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgw84kqj2k1bwq1/JapaneseEnglishData.xml?dl=1"
                   XPath="WordList/Word"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}}" DisplayMemberPath="English" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="179"/>
        <TextBox Name="searchBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="256,41,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=WordList/Word,BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142"/>
        <Label Content="SearchBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Search" Name="searchButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Height="36" Click="searchButton_Click"/>
        <Button Content="Speak" Name="speakButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,273,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Height="36" Click="speakButton_Click"/>
        <TextBox Name="searchResult" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="256,162,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=searchBox}" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

A sample of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--This is a generated XML File-->
<WordList>
  <Word>
    <English>Me</English>
    <Romaji>boku</Romaji>
    <Kanji>ぼく</Kanji>
  </Word>
  <Word>
    <English>I</English>
    <Romaji>boku</Romaji>
    <Kanji>ぼく</Kanji>
  </Word>
</WordList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DataContext of your Window or Grid in order to get your binding to work.[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part) might be helpful.

like so:

```
<Window
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
 Window>
<Window.Resources>
  <local:MyClass x:Key="MyClass">
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext={StaticResource MyClass}>
  ...
```

implementation for MyClass:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string _wordlist;
  private string _searchBox;

  public string WordList
  {
    get
    {
      return _wordlist;
    }
    set
    {
      _wordlist = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("WordList");
    }
  }

  public string searchBox
  {
    get
    {
      return _searchBox;
    }
    set
    {
      _searchBox= value;
      RaisePropertyChanged("searchBox");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, propertyName);
  }
}
```

You may need some additional logic inside the setters to translate using the XML.
Also, set the UpdateSourceTrigger for your TextBoxes to PropertyChanged:

```
 <TextBox Text={Binding Path=WordList, UpdatesourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} ... />
 <TextBox Text={Binding Path=searchBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged} ... />
```

I hope this gives you an idea how to get your desired behavior.